# PHP/MYSQL:Updated data isn't appearing on the table

Tags: php, mysql

Using php, i created an edit option that basically lets u change the data in the record. However, after clicking on submit, the data doesn't get saved on the table nor do i get any errors.. I am quite confused. Here r my codes:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php
      include('db.php');
      if (isset($_GET['Id'])) {
        $Id=$_GET['Id'];
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
          $Fname=$_POST['Fname'];
          $Lname=$_POST['Lname'];
          $Age=$_POST['Age'];
          $Nationality=$_POST['Nationality'];
          $PhoneNumber=$_POST['PhoneNumber'];
          $Email=$_POST['Email'];

          $query3=mysql_query("UPDATE `students` SET `Fname`='$Fname',`Lname`='$Lname',`Age`='$Age',`Nationality`='$Nationality',`PhoneNumber`='$PhoneNumber',`Email`='$Email' WHERE `Id`='$Id'");
          if($query3) {
            header('location:index1.php');
          }
        }
        $query1=mysql_query("select * from students where Id='$Id'");
        $query2=mysql_fetch_array($query1);
      ?>
      <form method="post" action="">
        First Name:<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $query2['Fname']; ?>" /><br />
        Last Name:<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $query2['Lname']; ?>" /><br />
        Age:<input type="text" name="age" value="<?php echo $query2['Age']; ?>" /><br />
        Nationality:<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $query2['Nationality']; ?>" /><br />
        Phone Number:<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $query2['PhoneNumber']; ?>" /><br />
        Email:<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $query2['Email']; ?>" /><br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update" />
      </form>
      <?php
    }
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: let's format your code, get rid of mysql_* functions and try again

Comment: try this to see if there is some SQL error. `if($query3){header('location:index1.php');}else{die(mysql_error());}`

Comment: I suggest removing all of your mysql_* functions and reading up on using prepared statements with mysqli_* functions, or PDO. mysqli_* functions are not only deprecated but open to sql injection attacks. Also, that header() call will not work as you have already outputted prior to that.

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac tried it.. No error.. The page went to index.1

Comment: @e4c5 get rid of it? what do i change it to?

Comment: I suggest you start using mysqli instead of mysql since mysql is deprecated now.

Comment: @MarkVincentManjac do i just replace where i put  mysql in my systen to mysqli? Sorry new to php so a little confused

Comment: switch to PDO it's better than mysqli. Just delete this code

Comment: something like this `$query3 = mysqli_query($con,'your query here')`. the `$con` is the variable you use in connecting to the database like `$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");` just look here [PHP mysqli_query() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp)

Comment: Please provide value of $Id from the form